# Is it safe to create `NSEvent object` then `CGEventPost` the `[ev CGEvent]` then exit the method?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsevent, cgeventtap

I have the following Objective-C snippet:

```
void toggle()
{
    NSEvent* down_event = [NSEvent keyEventWithType: NSEventTypeKeyDown
                                           location: NSZeroPoint
                                      modifierFlags: 0
                                          timestamp: 0.0
                                       windowNumber: 0
                                            context: nil
                                         characters: @" "
                        charactersIgnoringModifiers: @" "
                                          isARepeat: false
                                            keyCode: kVK_Space ];


    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, [down_event CGEvent]);
}
```

The project is ARC enabled.

Is this safe, or am I running the gauntlet of an occasional memory access error?

I'm worried that the `NSObject` may be garbage collected while the system is still making use of its `CGEvent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is safe. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1530429-cgevent?language=objc) for the `CGEvent` property states:

> The `CGEventRef` opaque type returned is autoreleased. If no `CGEventRef` object corresponding to the `NSEvent` object can be created, this method returns `NULL`.

This tells you that a new `CGEvent` is *created* that *corresponds* to the `NSEvent`. If there was a *dangerous* dependency, e.g. the return value contained an unsafe reference to the original object that would be noted *(there was/are methods that did/do that and were/are so documented [yes, I haven't checked if any still exist])*.

*BTW: if you grew up in the ARC age and do not know about "autoreleased" do not concern yourself, ARC knows and will do the right thing.*